# ViewModel Observer first argument is require Lifecycleowner

Tags: android, observable, viewmodel

I'm trying to use the android ViewModel and LiveData, but I getting an error when I want to create the observe. The first argument give me an error: wrong first argument type, and it is expect Lifecycleowner. If I try to build it: incompatible types: FragStat cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner
I'm using build tools 27.0.1 and the same for the support lib.

Here is my Fragment:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.konem.pubgstat.Adapters.StatAdapter;
import com.example.konem.pubgstat.LocalStatViewModel;
import com.example.konem.pubgstat.Models.LocalStat;
import com.example.konem.pubgstat.R;
import com.example.konem.pubgstat.Utils.LocalData.AppDatabase;
import com.example.konem.pubgstat.Utils.UserManager;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;
import java.util.List;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_frag_stat)
public class FragStat extends Fragment {
private List<LocalStat> localStats;
private StatAdapter statAdapter;
private AppDatabase appDatabase;
private UserManager userManager;


@ViewById
RecyclerView rvStats;

@AfterViews
void init() {
    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(getActivity());
    userManager = new UserManager(getActivity());
    LocalStatViewModel mViewModel = 
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LocalStatViewModel.class);


    statAdapter = new StatAdapter(localStats);

    rvStats.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    rvStats.setAdapter(statAdapter);
    subscribetostats(mViewModel);
}

private void subscribetostats(LocalStatViewModel localStatViewModel) {
    localStatViewModel.getList().observe(this, new Observer<List<LocalStat>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<LocalStat> localStats) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set the return type for getting records from DOA interface to
    `LiveData<List<LocatStat>> getAllStats();`

Then get Live data in  fragment,

```
LiveData<List<LocalStat> localStats;
```

Finally set Livedata observer in fragment

```
localStats.getList().observe(this, new Observer<List<LocalStat>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<LocalStat> localStats) {

        // Update UI

    }
});
```

Comment: This give me the same error unfortunately, 
localStats.getList().observe(this, new Observer<List<LocalStat>>()
in this line the this is wrong argument.

Answer (score 0):

So after few days trying I found the problem. You have to include this few lines in every fragment or activity, I thought is implemented by the appcombat but not...

```
private LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
    return mLifecycleRegistry;
}
```